# LOOKUP a key range in another key range to get ALL corresponding values, instead of just the first

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, one-to-many, lookup, array-formulas

I want to get ALL the data in Range1 corresponding to the keys in Range2.
(shown as below)

But my formula cannot show the data properly:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Range1,"select Col2 where Col1 contains '"&A1:A&"'",0)))
```

Anyone could help to tell me the problem in my formula?

## Range1

| Type | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| beverage | coke |
| food | cookies |
| food | bread |
| beverage | beer |
| beverage | coffee |
| food | chips |

## Range2 (ideal results)

| ColA(pre-set) | ColB(arrayformula in B1) | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| food | cookies | bread | chips |
| beverage | coke | beer | coffee |
| food | cookies | bread | chips |
| food | cookies | bread | chips |
| beverage | coke | beer | coffee |
| beverage | coke | beer | coffee |

## My exist result

| ColA(pre-set) | ColB(arrayformula in B1) | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| food | cookies | bread | chips |
| beverage | (cannot generate the output) |  |  |
| food |  |  |  |
| food |  |  |  |
| beverage |  |  |  |
| beverage |  |  |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your source data in columns A and B, and the max column width of the expected resut is 4, try:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), vlookup(A2:A, regexreplace({unique(A2:A),  split(trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(unique(A2:A))=A2:A)*len(A2:A),B2:B&",",),,50000))), ",")}, ",$", ), {1, 2, 3, 4}, 0),))
```

and see if that helps?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(TRANSPOSE(A12:A17)=A2:A7,B2:B7&"",),,2^9)),"")))
```

#### Size: 95 chars

#### Explanation:

- Create a 2D array comparing Range 1(`A2:A7`) vs transposed Range2(`A2:A17`)

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(A12:A17)=A2:A7)
  ```

| Range 1 v Range2 -> | food | beverage | food | food | beverage | beverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| beverage | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| food | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| food | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| beverage | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| beverage | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| food | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |

- Change TRUEs to Range1 Description(`B2:B7`) and a delimiter :

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRANSPOSE(A12:A17)=A2:A7,B2:B7&"",))
  ```

| Range 1 v Range2 -> | food | beverage | food | food | beverage | beverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| beverage |  | coke |  |  | coke | coke |
| food | cookies |  | cookies | cookies |  |  |
| food | bread |  | bread | bread |  |  |
| beverage |  | beer |  |  | beer | beer |
| beverage |  | coffee |  |  | coffee | coffee |
| food | chips |  | chips | chips |  |  |

- If you look vertically in each column, you have all the desired values for each required header. At this point, we use a classical query to do a vertical join:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(TRANSPOSE(A12:A17)=A2:A7,B2:B7&"",),,2^9))
  ```

| Range 1 v Range2 -> | food | beverage | food | food | beverage | beverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| beverage | cookies bread chips | coke beer coffee | cookies bread chips | cookies bread chips | coke beer coffee | coke beer coffee |
| food |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| food |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| beverage |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| beverage |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| food |  |  |  |  |  |  |

- Now, we just TRANSPOSE and SPLIT by the delimiter:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(TRANSPOSE(A12:A17)=A2:A7,B2:B7&"",),,2^9)),"")))
  ```

| Range 2 v | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| food | cookies | bread | chips |  |  |  |
| beverage | coke | beer | coffee |  |  |  |
| food | cookies | bread | chips |  |  |  |
| food | cookies | bread | chips |  |  |  |
| beverage | coke | beer | coffee |  |  |  |
| beverage | coke | beer | coffee |  |  |  |